# How to match Android Canvas to A3 paper size?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, isometric

Working with a Canvas in Android, user draws lines and then I would like to export the drawing to a PDF in A3 file size. How can this be done? Should I initially define the canvas to A3 file size?

Also, I would like that Canvas to have an "Isometric Graph File" background so the user can draw lines between the isometric graph edges. See image below:
[image: Isometric graph file]

How can this be done?

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: This really is two questions but both depend on if you have requirements to maintain a consistent scale between screen (and the isometric pattern) and paper (PDF) size? Or just scaled to fit? As you can draw any canvas using the in built  PdfDocument class but as PDF's have 72 points per inch measuring system without using some type of scale otherwise you won't have much drawing space. Also you need to think about how the different sizes of screens fit in to it.

Comment: @Andrew generally I have 2 main missions - first to have an isometric-paper-like background in my canvas that the user could draw lines between the triangles' edges, second to be able to export this isometric drawing to PDF A3 paper size. Maybe it would be easier to export first to dxf and then run some external tool to convert dxf to pdf?